# Is there a way to change scrollbar side in firefox for divs?

Tags: css, firefox, right-to-left

Is there a way to change scrollbar from right to left in divs? I tried applying direction: rtl; but apparently it does not have any affect in firefox. I would prefer a pure css solution but do not mind using js for this.

Comment: `direction: rtl;` works for me in Firefox 4 beta; I don't have Firefox 3.x handy to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with pure css and html, but you can use a jQuery plugin, like [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) that gives you the ability to use custom scrollbars, and choose their position in the page.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to this, except for implementing your own scrollbar functionality from scratch. The reason is that the scrollbar is actually an ui element inherited from the operating system, and not something the browser "owns" - and since the operating system doesn't support putting the scrollbar on the left hand side, neither does the browser.

Comment: Almost the entire Firefox window is owner-drawn, including the scrollbars.